# Performance Counter in .NET Framework For Network Traffic

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, performance, counter

because of having always open Oracle connections and want to track them down using performance counters. Because of missing admin rights I can't use the perfmon.
I googled and just found 1 promissing example but I can't manage to get it running and would really appreciate your help!

the performance Monitoring class (pmc) looks like this:

```
List<PerformanceCounter> lstPerfCounters = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
        public virtual void InitializeCounters(string AppInstanceName, Type PerfCountersList)
        {
            foreach (string counterName in Enum.GetNames(PerfCountersList))
            {
                PerformanceCounter PerfCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                PerfCounter.CategoryName = ".NET Data Provider for SqlServer";
                PerfCounter.CounterName = counterName;
                PerfCounter.InstanceName = AppInstanceName;
                lstPerfCounters.Add(PerfCounter);
            }
        }

        public virtual void PrintCounters()
        {
            foreach (PerformanceCounter p in lstPerfCounters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", p.CounterName, p.NextValue());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("****************************************************************");
        }
```

and has those enums:

```
public enum DBPerformanceCounters
        {
            NumberOfActiveConnectionPools,
            NumberOfActiveConnections,
            NumberOfFreeConnections,
            NumberOfNonPooledConnections,
            NumberOfPooledConnections,
            SoftDisconnectsPerSecond,
            SoftConnectsPerSecond,
            NumberOfReclaimedConnections,
            HardConnectsPerSecond,
            HardDisconnectsPerSecond,
            NumberOfActiveConnectionPoolGroups,
            NumberOfInactiveConnectionPoolGroups,
            NumberOfInactiveConnectionPools,
            NumberOfStasisConnections
        }
```

When starting my Programm I wanted to initialise it with the code given

```
PMC pc = new PMC();
string InstanceName = "myProgram";
pc.InitializeCounters(InstanceName, typeof(CountersList.DBPerformanceCounters));

pc.PrintCounters();
```

and here is the problem: the ide tells me, that CountersList doesn't exist. If I create a List for the DBPerformanceCounter manually, I get told that it is a varibale that is used like a type.
I'm sure its just a small bug, but I'm clueless and would really appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance.

*Earased some typos.

Comment: `because of having always open Oracle connections` don't use such connections. No matter of network monitoring are going to fix the scaleability and locking issues caused by long-lived connections. All types of Oracle providers use connection pooling. Even if you say "but Oracle doesn't block", it *does* have to load old row versions from the redo files, eating up the disk bandwidth

Comment: BTW that's the real bandwidth you need to check - the IO bandwidth in the DB server's log file. A simple UPDATE from the client will generate a new entry in the redo file. Applications that try to read that record will read it from the redo log

Comment: As for *Oracle's* performance counters, you should check the documentation of the Oracle driver you use. Which one are you using?

Comment: You don't need to create an application to gather perf counters either. You can create a trace log in Performance Monitor, specify which counters you want and how often to retrieve them, and just let it run. Performance Counters are a Windows feature

Comment: My problem: I got the task to realise those Performance Counters per Code. The explanation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performance-counters didn't really help me and there is no good code example for them.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to replicate what Windows already does very well, to fix a bug that has nothing to do with them. Long-lived connections =bad. Don't use them. The ADO.NET counters work for *every* ADO.NET provider. If you want counters specific to a provider, you need to check that provider's docs, not ADO.NET's. Or just open Performance Monitor and check which providers are there

Comment: Using perf counters is very well documented too, just not in the ADO.NET sections, because it's not an ADO.NET feature. If you check the [PerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) class's docs you'll find examples that show how to create perf counters or read them. The class is even a component you can put on a form directly

Comment: I just found that those enums are in the class CountersList but my Programm crashes when trying to print the connections...